# Installing WIndows 8(ISO) on ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, installation

in **windows 7,** just mounted the **windows 8 iso image** and i ran **setup.exe** . it upgraded to windows 8.
but **in ubuntu 13.10** i cannot do so,i even tried booting from USB,"it says "failed to load operating system"..what now, should i do to **install windows** ?
dont need any part of ubuntu .just want to erase entirely, including boot memory.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you talking about two different machines? And the latter one is a dual boot one? Can you please clarify? Also, don't use so much **bold** and please capitalize the I properly

Comment: Burn the .iso to a disk then just boot to it.

Answer (score 1):

To erase Ubuntu you'll need a bootable USB or DVD with Windows. I see from your question that you have tried to install from USB.

A bootable Windows USB in Ubuntu can be made only with [WinUSB](http://en.congelli.eu/prog_info_winusb.html) which is free/open-source and can be installed with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install winusb
```

If you have another Windows machine, you can make a Windows bootable USB using [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/), which is free.

Comment: I tried that too,i changed the boot priority to USB and loaded it says"Missng operating system"